# error[E0282]: type annotations needed --> /libp2p-noise-0.32.0/src/protocol/x25519.rs:221:45

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

While `running` this project https://github.com/jimmychu0807/substrate-offchain-worker-demo
I'm geting this error:

> error[E0282]: type annotations needed --> /libp2p-noise-0.32.0/src/protocol/x25519.rs:221:45

Answer (score 0):

This error looks an issue with versions, you are trying to run an example very old. You can try to fix it, see for example this previous StackExchange question similar to your error: [type annotations needed in libp2p-noise](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/type-annotations-needed-in-libp2p-noise).

But I would suggest to check the Substrate documentation: [Add offchain workers](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-offchain-workers/) where you have the [Offchain Worker Example Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker).

There is also a PR open in Substrate with a new example: [refactor Offchain Worker examples](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14280)